# Write calculation output in a txt file

Tags: c++

This a very beginner question. I'm trying to create a simple c++ switch case based console calculator that creates a txt file and writes the output to it. I have very little experience with OOPS or C++ so I have no clue on how to make this work.

This snippet creates a text file and writes to it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");

    MyFile << "Lorem ipsum dolor amet";

    MyFile.close();
}
```

When I try to add this to my calculator code, it gives me a bunch of errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char op;
    float num1, num2;

    cout << "Enter Operator: +, -, *, / : ";
    cin >> op;

    cout << "Enter two Operands: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2;

    switch(op)
    {
        case '+':
            cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << num1 + num2;
            ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
            MyFile << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << num1 + num2;
            MyFile.close();
        break;

        case '-':
            cout << num1 << " - " << num2 << " = " << num1 - num2;
            ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
            MyFile << num1 << " - " << num2 << " = " << num1 - num2;
            MyFile.close();
        break;
        
        case '*':
            cout << num1 << " * " << num2 << " = " << num1 * num2;
            ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
            MyFile << num1 << " * " << num2 << " = " << num1 * num2;
            MyFile.close();
        break;
        
        case '/':
            cout << num1 << " / " << num2 << " = " << num1 / num2;
            ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
            MyFile << num1 << " / " << num2 << " = " << num1 / num2;
            MyFile.close();
        break;

        default:
            cout << "Error! Operator is not correct";
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error messages in the console:

```
calctext.cpp: In function 'int main()':
calctext.cpp:25:14: error: jump to case label
   25 |         case '-':
      |              ^~~
calctext.cpp:20:18: note:   crosses initialization of 'std::ofstream MyFile'      
   20 |         ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
      |                  ^~~~~~
calctext.cpp:27:18: error: redeclaration of 'std::ofstream MyFile'
   27 |         ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
      |                  ^~~~~~
calctext.cpp:20:18: note: 'std::ofstream MyFile' previously declared here
   20 |         ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
      |                  ^~~~~~
calctext.cpp:32:14: error: jump to case label
   32 |         case '*':
      |              ^~~
calctext.cpp:20:18: note:   crosses initialization of 'std::ofstream MyFile'      
   20 |         ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
      |                  ^~~~~~
calctext.cpp:34:18: error: redeclaration of 'std::ofstream MyFile'
   34 |         ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
      |                  ^~~~~~
calctext.cpp:20:18: note: 'std::ofstream MyFile' previously declared here
   20 |         ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
      |                  ^~~~~~
calctext.cpp:39:14: error: jump to case label
   39 |         case '/':
      |              ^~~
calctext.cpp:20:18: note:   crosses initialization of 'std::ofstream MyFile'      
   20 |         ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
      |                  ^~~~~~
calctext.cpp:41:18: error: redeclaration of 'std::ofstream MyFile'
   41 |         ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
      |                  ^~~~~~
calctext.cpp:20:18: note: 'std::ofstream MyFile' previously declared here
   20 |         ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
      |                  ^~~~~~
calctext.cpp:46:9: error: jump to case label
   46 |         default:
      |         ^~~~~~~
calctext.cpp:20:18: note:   crosses initialization of 'std::ofstream MyFile'      
   20 |         ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
```

Comment: what is a bunch of errors? Please include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: Just a suspicion: The problem is that you do it in `case` branches (in the 2nd exposed code). Declaring/defining variables in `case` branches conflicts with the scope of your `switch`. (I mean where the curly brackets are set.) Please, enclose every `case` branch in curly braces to fix this, e.g. `case '+': {`... `} break;`.

Comment: btw you don't need to call `MyFile.close()`. The destructor already does that. Not writing `MyFile.close()` has the added benefit that you can more easily replace the `ofstream` with some other output stream for testing and debugging

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Explicitly closing a stream would have the advantage that the success of that could be tested afterwards. (`close()` may cause to dump out the internal buffer which could fail.) Of course, `close()` doesn't provide any added value without... ;-)

Comment: Also, as a matter of style and readability, you may want to indent the code between 'case' and 'break'. This way you'll know at a glance, where a block starts and where it ends.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback and help. I restructured my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of a variable declared inside a `switch` is the entire `switch`-block - a `case` is not a separate scope.
This leads to two problems:

- Multiple declarations of the same variable name, and
- Jumping across a variable initialization, which you're not allowed to do.

The trivial fix is to wrap each case in a pair of curly braces, adding a new scope:

```
case '+':
{
    ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
    cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << num1 + num2;
    MyFile << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << num1 + num2;
    // You don't need to explicitly close a file, its destruction takes care of it.
    break;
}
```

but I would remove the code duplication instead:

```
bool valid_op = true;
float result = 0;
switch(op)
{
    case '+':
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case '*':
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case '/':
        result = num1 / num2;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Error! Operator is not correct";
        valid_op = false;
        break;
}
if (valid_op)
{
    ofstream MyFile("filename.txt");
    cout << num1 << ' ' << op << ' ' << num2 << " = " << result;
    MyFile << num1 << ' ' << op << ' ' << num2 << " = " << result;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. The code looks clean and efficient, I have yet to read up on boolean in C++.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what is "float result = 0" being used for??

Comment: It's the result value that is updated in the switch and output in the results.

Answer (score 1):

The variables declared in a `switch` block have their scope as that `switch` block. So the `MyFile` object in `+` case is visible in `-` case. So compiler thinks you have declared a variable with same name again.

You can possibly change the variable name for each case or, do something like this.

```
int main()
{
    char op;
    float num1, num2;

    cout << "Enter Operator: +, -, *, / : ";
    cin >> op;

    cout << "Enter two Operands: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2;

    ofstream MyFile;
    switch(op)
    {
        case '+':
        MyFile = ofstream("filename.txt");
        cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << num1 + num2;
        MyFile << num1 << " + " << num2 << " = " << num1 + num2;
        MyFile.close();
        break;

        case '-':
        MyFile = ofstream("filename.txt");
        cout << num1 << " - " << num2 << " = " << num1 - num2;
        MyFile << num1 << " - " << num2 << " = " << num1 - num2;
        MyFile.close();
        break;
        
        case '*':
        MyFile = ofstream("filename.txt");
        cout << num1 << " * " << num2 << " = " << num1 * num2;
        MyFile << num1 << " * " << num2 << " = " << num1 * num2;
        MyFile.close();
        break;
        
        case '/':
        MyFile = ofstream("filename.txt");
        cout << num1 << " / " << num2 << " = " << num1 / num2;
        MyFile << num1 << " / " << num2 << " = " << num1 / num2;
        MyFile.close();
        break;

        default:
        cout << "Error! Operator is not correct";
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not (only) the issue of duplicated identifiers. Even if they would be not duplicated, the compiler would complain. It doesn't like the fact that a definition could be skipped depending on which case is branched into. (Keep in mind that the `break` is not mandatory. "Falling through" case branches is allowed as well.)